# Date range in DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, date-and-time

I am trying to plot the following figures but I cannot get the date range that I would like to have. I would like to have a date range like 1960,1970,1980....2020

```
exter={{22.2478, 22.2613, 22.2361, 22.2683, 22.3835, 22.5375, 22.4802, 
         22.5564, 22.5688, 22.5644, 22.6113, 22.6104, 22.6985, 22.6889, 
         22.7512, 22.7282, 22.7886, 22.7418, 22.7474, 22.7167, 22.7466, 
         22.8064, 22.7779, 22.758, 22.7547, 22.7707, 22.7779, 22.8043, 
         22.8652, 22.8549, 22.8501, 22.8497, 22.8323, 22.898, 22.8078, 
         22.8364, 22.8967, 22.9342, 22.9303, 22.9757, 23.014, 23.0658, 
         23.1099, 23.177, 23.245, 23.3148, 23.3909, 23.4711, 23.546, 23.6342,
         23.7322, 23.7863, 23.8596, 23.9089, 23.9548, 23.9836, 24.0191, 
         Log[""]}, 
        {21.9362, 21.9975, 22.0117, 22.0723, 22.0611, 22.1091, 
         22.1242, 22.2045, 22.2241, 22.3412, 22.5447, 22.6301, 22.7101, 
         22.7358, 22.8, 22.7805, 22.7851, 22.714, 22.6866, 22.719, 22.8537, 
         22.9718, 22.9978, 23.0135, 22.9942, 23.0614, 23.0821, 23.0936, 
         23.1664, 23.2171, 23.2846, 23.3385, 23.244, 23.2544, 23.3428, 
         23.3444, 23.4429, 23.4694, 23.4978, 23.4896, 23.4586, 23.4729, 
         23.3797, 23.1934, 23.1336, 23.0748, 23.0396, 23.0024, 22.8079, 
         22.9214, 23.0399, 23.1836, 23.3214, 23.3752, 23.3963, 23.413, 
         23.4192}}
```

My code so far is:

```
DateListPlot[exter, {1960}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Dashed, Red}}, 
    PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Years", "Log GDP"}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], 
    ImageSize -> 450, AspectRatio -> 0.75, 
    ImageMargins -> 60]
```

[image]

Comment: THE CODE  `DateListPlot[exter, {1960},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Dashed, Red}}, PlotRange -> All,
 Joined -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Years", "Log GDP"},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold],
 ImageSize -> 450, AspectRatio -> 0.75,
 ImageMargins -> 60]`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just missing one or two bits:

1. The date spec `{1960}` starts in 1960 and goes through today.  You can use `{{1960}, {2020}}` to go all the way to 2020.
2. You can specify the ticks to show using something like:

   `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Table[{y}, {y, 1960, 2020, 10}], None}}`

Those frame ticks will be minimal, just labeling the decades on the bottom frame edge.  You can add minor ticks on the bottom edge and unlabeled ticks on the top edge with a bit more code.